# Impose a condition needing to be satisfied before user changes to another tab

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I have situation where I need to make sure that user has completed certain steps before they move to another tab inside `UITabBarController`. So if the user is in middle of something and taps on another tab, I would like to show a `UIAlertView` saying "you must complete blah blah blah before you go to another tab."

Is it possible to to check this condition and cancel moving to another view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can. I suppose you have your tabbar controller in the AppDelegate class. If so, set the AppDelegate to be its delegate. Then implement the following method

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {
  // place all the checks here
  EditingViewController *editingController = //link to controller where editing is being made.
  if (editingController && editingController.isEditing) {
    //UIAlertView
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At a guess you could try catching the view on it's way out and changing the selected index on the tab bar controller to be the view you wish to keep them on:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
   self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
}
```

You might find that's a bit jerky though depending on the order of events, a quick google has found that if you can make your view controller a UITabBarControllerDelegate then you can implement:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Which would allow you to catch them earlier. You might find it simplest to implement this in your App Delegate and have it know (or check) if it should allow the change away.